How to add contacts from WhatsApp in the Script Rehearser app?
I am using the Script Rehearser app from the Google Play store. This app lets me hold imaginary conversations with contacts (which, may be real, or imaginary). I can use the app to plan what I want to say, and conversations I want to have, ... or to plan a conversation for a book, for a television show, or a YouTube channel.
I wonder whether there is a way to include profile pictures of contacts from WhatsApp, in the Script Rehearsal app. This would be useful. I could then even search by contact, my script, and reversions.
How do I do this?
